# How do i enter data into a google/online spreadsheet through a custom form that i designed using html css

Tags: forms, spreadsheet

I have made a form using html/css and now i want to write the input data into a google/online spreadsheet. How can i achieve this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Use pHp to either connect to an OCDB driver (that is connected to your spreadsheet) or to simply write to an XLS file on the server.